# iRobot Create 2 useful for starters

Tags: ros, create2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Community,

has anyone experience with iRobot Create 2 ?

http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2.aspx

Which lowlevel drivers are compatible with device ?
Can I use turtlebot compatible parts ?

Thanks for some hints

Cheers
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202147/irobot-create-2-useful-for-starters/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2015-01-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rzwemer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21542/rzwemer/) on 2015-01-31**:
I'm a NOOB, attempting to load ROS Indigo on a Raspberry Pi connected to an iRobot Create 2.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just tried using a bunch of old iRobot Create drivers with the iRobot Create 2.  None of them seem to work.  I'm going to investigate more and then probably end up writing my own which I will publish open source.  Hopefully it will just be a matter of extending old code.

---

Originally posted by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) with karma: 350 on 2015-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you made any progress? I'm hoping to use the iRobot Create 2 as well, but I haven't found anyone that's managed to get it running in ROS Indigo.

---

Originally posted by [barelySentient](https://answers.ros.org/users/22523/barelysentient/) with karma: 21 on 2015-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on 2015-06-26**:
I've been super lazy with respect to that so.. no.   The other day I was attempting to run stuff again with no luck.  I tried running the python control script provided by iRobot and that mostly worked so I'm going to see if I can perhaps alter that to accept a twist on cmd_vel.

**Comment by [barelySentient](https://answers.ros.org/users/22523/barelysentient/) on 2015-06-27**:
That's fine.  We had a few robotic gaming demos to host involving the iRobot Create 2, so we were in dire need of a solution. We ended up using PyGame and PySerial packages to communicate with the iRobot Create 2 for teleoperation. Would our code help you in developing a driver in ROS?

**Comment by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on 2015-06-29**:
That would be great!  Is it on Github?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone interested, I have released the source code for my driver that is compatible with Create 1 and 2. http://wiki.ros.org/create_autonomy

Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2